# Can't make :focus or click animation vue, gsap, css

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, gsap

```
<div class="shippingRadioWrap">
  <div>
    <div class="radioBtn">
      <div class="inner">
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="radio" value=3.50 name="shipping" v-model="shipping" class="shippingRadio">Some inner text
  </div>
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Basicly I have css hover animation for "inner" class.

```
.shippingRadioWrap:hover .inner{
    transform: rotate(280deg);
    bottom: 0;
}
```

It is custom radio, `:focus` don't work. Can't figure how to animate with gsap and vue.js either.

It needs to stay animated on click and it should act as a radio if one of the same .inner is clicked others disables

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking. Could you try to explain it more?

Comment: One note, `.shippingRadioWrap:hover .inner{}` should be seperated by `,` = `.shippingRadioWrap:hover, .inner{}`